# Spring WebSocket ConvertAndSendToUser not working but convertAndSend working

Tags: java, spring-websocket, stomp

I am new to Spring boot websocket and messaging semantics. Currently i am able to send private messages using the below code.

```
String queueName = "/user/" + username  + "/queue/wishes";
simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend(queueName, message);
```

When trying to use convertAndSendToUser I am not getting any error but the message is not getting sent. I knew that with sendToUser there should be a slight change in how the destination name should be formed but I am not getting it right.

```
String queueName = "/user/queue/wishes";
simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(username, queueName, message);
```

Below is my subscription code.

```
stompClient.subscribe('/user/queue/wishes', function(message) {
    alert(message);
})
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally figured out the problem. I did a silly mistake. I was filling the User DestinationPrefix as part of WebSocket config. but didn't set it up for the injected bean SimpMessaging template.

Comment: Could you please share the solution with your answer.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem, if your `username` is actually a `sessionId`, then try to use one of the overloaded methods that accept headers (so said in [SimpMessageSendingOperations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/simp/SimpMessageSendingOperations.html) javadoc):

```
SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor = SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.create(SimpMessageType.MESSAGE);
headerAccessor.setSessionId(username);
headerAccessor.setLeaveMutable(true);

messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(username, "/queue/wishes", message, headerAccessor.getMessageHeaders());
```

[my example](https://github.com/xMandrake/spring-boot-ws-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/ws/websocket/WebSocketController.java)

Answer (score 0):

It is not getting sent because your "destination" i.e "queuename" is incorrect. 
As you can see here [SimpMessagingTemplate.java#L230](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/78d1591e2ddfe01f05b9d09e68a00e7ad54c885a/spring-messaging/src/main/java/org/springframework/messaging/simp/SimpMessagingTemplate.java#L230) this is the method that gets invoked as a part of the chain on invocations of `template.convertAndSendToUser()`.

This method already prefixes `/user` to the final destination. So instead you should do something like this:
`simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(username,"/queue/wishes", message);`
Now with the correct destination it should get sent to user.

Comment: No. It's still not working. I ended up adding "/user" to the destination after initially, it didn't work with "/queue/wishes" destination.

Answer (score 0):

You must registry the prefix of SimpleBroker:

```
@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/queue", "/user");
    registry.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user");
}
```

Although the UserDestinationPrefix has been set for default value "/user/", you must to add the SimpleBroker prefix.