# Why can I subscribe to destination but I don't receive any messages for that user with Spring WebSocket STOMP (with Spring Security and Keycloak)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websocket, stomp

I'm trying to implement a microservice for sending messages via WebSocket.

I can send correctly messages to a client subcribed and authenticated (passing the JWT token to the WebClient server), but now I want send messages only to a particular user.

Following the [official spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#websocket-stomp-user-destination) I can have the client correctly subscribed but I don't get any message.

---

**WebSocket Server configuration:**

- **WebSecurityConfig.java**

```
[...]
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.cors()
                .and().csrf().disable()

                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
        ;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/ws/**");
    }
[...]
```

- **WebSocketConfig.java**

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
//@EnableScheduling
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Qualifier("websocket")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    public WebSocketConfig(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
    {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOrigins("*")
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
        registration.interceptors(new ChannelInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
                StompHeaderAccessor headerAccessor =
                        MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor.class);

                if (StompCommand.CONNECT.equals(headerAccessor.getCommand()))
                {
//                  log.info("TOKEN: {}", headerAccessor.getNativeHeader("token").toString());
                    Optional.ofNullable(headerAccessor.getNativeHeader("token")).ifPresent(ah ->
                    {
                        String bearerToken = ah.get(0).replace("Bearer ", "");
                        JWSAuthenticationToken token = (JWSAuthenticationToken) authenticationManager
                                .authenticate(new JWSAuthenticationToken(bearerToken));
                        headerAccessor.setUser(token);
                    });
                }

                return message;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {

        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/queue");
    }
}
```

- **WebSocketSecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class WebSocketSecurityConfig extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {

        messages
                .simpTypeMatchers(CONNECT, HEARTBEAT, UNSUBSCRIBE, DISCONNECT).permitAll()
                .simpDestMatchers("/app/**", "/topic/**", "/queue/**").authenticated()
                .simpSubscribeDestMatchers("/topic/**", "/queue/**", "/user/**").authenticated()
                .anyMessage().denyAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean sameOriginDisabled() {
        //disable CSRF for websockets for now...
        return true;
    }
}
```

- In a Java class I tryied both `convertAndSend` and `convertAndSendToUser` (probably a better choice) functions for send the message:

```
simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/user/" +  username + "/queue/private-messages", message);


simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser("user","/queue/private-messages", message);
```

---

**WebSocket Client configurations**

- **WebSecurityConfig.java**

```
[...]
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        super.configure(http);

        http.cors()
                .and().csrf().disable()

                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()

        ;
    }
[...]
```

- **StompClient.java** where i use the function `createAndConnectClient` for create the connection

```
[...]
    public void createAndConnectClient(String accessToken) {

        WebSocketClient client = new StandardWebSocketClient();
        WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(client);

        stompClient.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());

        StompSessionHandler sessionHandler = new MyStompSessionHandler(stompConfig);

        // connect with custom headers
        final WebSocketHttpHeaders headers = new WebSocketHttpHeaders();
        final StompHeaders head = new StompHeaders();
        head.add("token", accessToken);
        stompClient.connect(serverURL, headers, head, sessionHandler);
    }
[...]
```

- **MyStompSessionHandler**

```
@Component
public class MyStompSessionHandler extends StompSessionHandlerAdapter {

    private final StompConfig stompConfig;

    @Autowired
    public MyStompSessionHandler(StompConfig stompConfig) {
        this.stompConfig = stompConfig;
    }


    @Override
    public void afterConnected(StompSession session, StompHeaders connectedHeaders) {
        log.info("New session established : " + session.getSessionId());
        session.subscribe("/user/queue/private-messages", this);
        log.info("Subscribed to /user/queue/private-messages");
    }

    @Override
    public void handleException(StompSession session, StompCommand command, StompHeaders headers, byte[] payload, Throwable exception) {
        log.error("Got an exception", exception);
    }

    @Override
    public Type getPayloadType(StompHeaders headers) {
        return Message.class;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleFrame(StompHeaders headers, Object payload) {

        if (payload != null) {
            Message msg = (Message) payload;
            log.info("Received : " + msg.getText() + " from : " + msg.getFrom());
        } else {
            log.info("NULL Payload");
        }
    }
}
```

---

As I said I can subscribe to the destination but I don't receive any message.

---

EDIT: I added this code when I send the message

```
[...]
SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor = SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.create(SimpMessageType.MESSAGE);
JWSAuthenticationToken token = null;
    try {
            token = userService.getToken(message.getTo());
            log.info("TOKEN BEFORE SEND: {}", token);
        } catch (NotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.error("User isn't connected");
        }
        headerAccessor.setUser(token);
        headerAccessor.setSessionId(userService.getSessionId(message.getTo()));
        log.info("SESSION-ID: {}", headerAccessor.getSessionId());
        log.info("HEADER: {}", headerAccessor.toString());
        simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(message.getTo(), webSocketConfig.getDestination(), message, headerAccessor.getMessageHeaders());
[...]
```

and so... I'm sure the user (and the SessionID too) is the same. but still not receinving nothing on my client!

---

**WORKING SOLUTION:**

**Not the thing I want but... it works!   ¯_(ツ)_/¯**

**(no benefit from STOMP mechanisms for users management)**

When I subscribe to destination, in my Client, I add to destionation url the name of the user

`"/queue/messages-" + user.getName()`.

Using `convertAndSend` on that destination (Server side that send messages and without headers) I can send private messages to `user`.

Comment: `convertAndSendToUser` will simply ignore any messages sent to it's queues if the sent user, destination or session does not exist, that is mostly the case here. Could you confirm by debugging if the user you set here                      `headerAccessor.setUser(token)` is same as the user you are passing in convertAndSendToUser() ? You can do this by printing getUser() and printing the username you are passing.

Comment: same user! I'm sure about this as I print the username that is in the token and it is the same that I pass to `convertAndSendToUser()`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is happening because the [DefaultSimpUserRegistry](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/messaging/DefaultSimpUserRegistry.html) is not getting updated with the user. If you see this [line](https://github.com/BrightStarry/spring-source-code/blob/a3c256000ca5b45bfe60c234844348edb742450f/spring-websocket/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/socket/messaging/DefaultSimpUserRegistry.java#L95) where it is supposed to add the user, it does not add from the STOMP headerAccesssor but from the from the sub-protocol i.e websocket protocol. So you will have to set the user for the websocket session.

```
private void populateSecurityContextHolder(String
            username, List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities) {
        PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken authToken = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(
                username, null, grantedAuthorities);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
    }
```

So on setting this, the user registry should get updated with the user and hence when the message is sent to the queue when it finds the user it should be able to send it to the user, rather than discarding the message because the user was not present.

Comment: No way :-( it doesn't work... I still receiving nothing! However, unless I'm wrong, the protocol is WebSocket and the sub-protocol is STOMP. So it should be fine set it in STOMP headerAccessor.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the UserDestinationPrefix for SimpMessagingTemplate. If not can you please try setting that to '/user & see if it works.

Comment: Isn't it "/user" by default?

Comment: I don't think so. I had a similar problem and setting this solved the issue for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62456213/spring-websocket-convertandsendtouser-not-working-but-convertandsend-working

Comment: More than setting the `/user` prefix (that I tried anyway) I was curious about passing the header set with `headerAccessor.setUser(token)` to `convertAndSendToUser` as I saw in this [answer in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62524099/11621071)... but still not working!!!

Answer (score 0):

**Not the thing I want but... it works!   ¯_(ツ)_/¯**

**(no benefit from STOMP mechanisms for users management)**

When I subscribe to destination, in my Client, I add to destionation url the name of the user:

`"/queue/messages-" + user.getName()`.

Using `convertAndSend` on that destination (Server side that send messages) I can send private messages to `user`.